# How to "shutdown" a socket in R?

Tags: r, sockets, connection, ipc

I have a `socketConnection` in R that requires a shutdown (SHUT_WR) to be called so the server can continue working but I can't close the connection because it will still read. I went through all the manuals I could find but R capabilities for socket connections seem limited (missing shutdown and other features you can find in other languages). Is there any resource around the theme or is it really a deficiency?

Comment: FWIW, `grep -rn src -e "shutdown"` in the top level directory of R's sources does not reveal any calls to `shutdown`, so socket shutdowns may very well not be implemented.  On the other hand, that's just a static analysis. You might have better luck asking on the R-devel mailing list.

Comment: I actually did some deep source code digging, looks like there is nothing around that supports it, the C source code for connections shows the lack of options.